# Face Detection Asus TF201

Tags: android, face-detection

I try to develop detection the face on the tablet Asus TF201. However, the application shuts down when I start face detection.

is there any  possibility this tablet does not to support face detection ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FaceDetection is a software feature, so it should be supported on your Asus tablet. Have a look in the logs, you should be able to find there the source of the application crash.